# Using the rollout restart command in cronjob, in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I want to periodically restart the deployment using k8s cronjob.

Please check what is the problem with the yaml file.

When I execute the command from the local command line, the deployment restarts normally, but it seems that the restart is not possible with cronjob.
e.g $ kubectl rollout restart deployment my-ingress -n my-app

### my cronjob yaml file

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: deployment-restart
  namespace: my-app
spec:
  schedule: '0 8 */60 * *' 
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 2 
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 600 
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: deployment-restart 
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
            - name: kubectl
              image: bitnami/kubectl:latest 
              command:
                - 'kubectl'
                - 'rollout'
                - 'restart'
                - 'deployment/my-ingress -n my-app'
```

Comment: share your RBAC permission and service account YAML config so get iead might be issue of permission.

Comment: You probably mean the very last line to be three separate words, and they should be on three separate lines.  (You'd get the same error if you run `'kubectl' 'rollout' 'restart' 'deployment/my-ingress -n my-app'` in your local shell.)

Comment: Need to agree with previous comment. Could you please add the logs from the `CronJob`  (`Pod`) that are showing what exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as David suggested run cron of **kubectl** is like by executing the command

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-jp-runner
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl rollout restart deployment my-ingress -n my-app
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

i would also suggest you to check the **role** and **service account** permissions

example for ref :

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: kubectl-cron
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  verbs:
  - 'patch'

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: kubectl-cron
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-kubectl-cron
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: kubectl-cron
  apiGroup: ""

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-kubectl-cron
  namespace: default

---
```

Comment: Thank you. Again, you helped
After creating a service account and modifying the yaml file to suit my server, it works as desired!!!!!